# Database Editing in Session OnEnd Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection

I was Creating a website in Classic ASP Project, having a Logout feature.
I want to access the login  database and make changes, when the session ends. The coding is something like:

In global.asa :

```
Sub Session_OnEnd()
Set studcon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
studcon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = E:\mailfan.mdb"
Set studrec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
studrec.Open "login", studcon, 1, 3

studrec.movefirst
found = 0
Do While studrec.EOF or found = 1
    If studrec("ID") = Session("uid") Then
    studrec("log") = 0
    studrec.Update
    End If
    studrec.movenext
Loop
studrec.close
studcon.close
Set studrec = Nothing
Set studcon = Nothing
End Sub
```

But Even After    Session.Abandon    the value of log field Remains the same (It is 1 when session's active).

Small Update: I tried to google it, and did recieve a very similar link having the same question: http://www.justskins.com/forums/problem-with-global-asa-77015.html

But the code is the same as suggested by Aaron Bertrand in the above link. Is it due to IIS 8.0? Because I would be Running it on Win XP sp3 IIS 6. And I Do require it to work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see an SQL query anywhere in your code.  If  you're intent on using a recordset for your update then in place of

```
studrec.Open "login", studcon, 1, 3
```

you should have something like

```
studrec.Open "select * from login", studcon, 1, 3
```

This assumes that your database table is called "Login"

Using a recordset is actually an over complex means of doing all this though, An Update query should suffice.  You could remove all your code from

```
Set studrec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

to

```
studrec.close
```

and replace it with

```
studcon.Execute("UPDATE Login set log = 0 where id = " & Session("uid"))
```

Comment: Or even safer use `ADODB.Command` to execute the SQL `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with SQL was that we were sepecifically instructed with not using SQL. Though the code containing SQL did work well.

Comment: @newcode Two more things I've just noticed about your recordset.  First, if you're only retrieving a single record then you don't need a `Do While...Loop`.  Second, if you were retrieving multiple records and you did need to loop through then you should use `Do While Not studrec.EOF`. EOF stands for 'end of field' and you want the code to be executed if you haven't reached the end of your recordset, not if you have.

Comment: @newcode Who specifically tells someone not to use SQL? Its far more efficient then building a `ADODB.Recordset` just to then have to iterate through it updating records individually.